# Error while inserting picture into sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, openrowset

I am trying to insert a 'png ' image into an sql table field(called barchart,which is of type blob) with the below query.

`INSERT INTO disease_symptom_soc(barchart) Values ((SELECT BULKColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'/home/barchartC2936861.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Image)) where disease_id='C2936861';`

I am getting the below error.What could be the reason?

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(BULK N'/home/barchart' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

i guess u can use LOAD_FILE

Example:

```
INSERT INTO expBLOB(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('/some/path/image.png'))
```

Comment: hi i tried as :INSERT INTO disease_symptom_soc(barchart) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('path/barchartC2936861.png')) WHERE disease_id='C2936861'; BUT i am getting error:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE disease_id='C2936861'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

If you can, then change the DataType of the column to '**image**'. Depending on the sql server version you are using. Otherwise if it oracle based db , you will have to create a loadfile proc and execute it as follows:
http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-insert-blob-dataimage-video-into.html

Comment: I'm affraid your link is not active anymore

Answer (score 0):

MySql OpenrowSet isn't used to copy files into the database but to query an external file (csv, xls) with a connection string, for example

```
OPENROWSET ('MSDASQL','mysql connection string','query')
```

I suggest you to load the file with a simple program made in any language (I don't know if you are developing in php, c#...) and pass it already loaded in memory to the db with a simple insert query.

Comment: Then in the link here ,are they not referring to the image to be loaded? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2007/09/26/Insert-binary-data-like-images-into-SQL-Server-without-front-end.aspx

Comment: As I know that type of sintax has worked for a while on older versions of sqlServer: I've tryed to use these some years ago but have got me more problems than semplifications: first of all the "@" parameterized function hasn't been working a single time make me swearing because I've got to make a query for every filename: another big flaw of this sintax is that you MUST have the same directory for every pc where you install your program and this is a very big limitation: I recommend you to make a little effort to write something less bounded, more flexible and debuggable.